# Is there a difference between flit install and pip install?

Tags: python, pip, flit

[flit](https://flit.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) provides an `install` option. I just wonder what is the difference between `flit install --symlink` and `pip install --editable .`, or more generally, `flit install` and `pip install`? Unfortunately the documentation is currently not clear about this at all:

> Install the package on your system.
>
> By default, the package is installed to the same Python environment that Flit itself is installed in; use --python or FLIT_INSTALL_PYTHON to override this.
>
> If you don’t have permission to modify the environment (e.g. the system Python on Linux), Flit may do a user install instead. Use the --user or --env flags to force this one way or the other, rather than letting Flit guess.

They both seem to be doing the same thing, when should I use `pip` and when `flit`?

Answer (score 1):

With a normal install, they're both doing the same thing - whichever tool you call, Flit builds a wheel and pip installs it. There was more difference in the past (like the auto user installation mentioned in the docs you quoted), but now it's almost exactly the same.

Flit's `--symlink` option achieves a similar result to `--editable` but works in a different way (which I happen to prefer :-). The `--pth-file` option should be identical to `--editable`.